# Memory error when exporting task

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, memory

I'm trying to get a building density map per square km of Africa. The following code will run ~15 hours and then report a memory error. How can I avoid this?

```
var buildings = ee.FeatureCollection('GOOGLE/Research/open-buildings/v1/polygons').filterBounds(ee.Geometry(geometry))

var countImg = buildings.reduceToImage({
    properties: [],
    reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(),
  })
 // .reproject('epsg:4326',null, 1000);
  
Export.image.toAsset({
  image: countImg,
  description: 'CountBuildings',
  assetId: 'CountBuildings',
  scale: 1000,
  region: geometry
});
```

Where geometry is a polygon over Africa:

```
var geometry = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-23.890014501006107, 38.38461019038489],
          [-23.890014501006107, -36.906099725897505],
          [52.750610498993886, -36.906099725897505],
          [52.750610498993886, 38.38461019038489]]], null, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider breaking the geometry into several smaller ones and run seperate exports. Be aware that what your are trying is memory intensive and probably will also result in memory errors on the country level if there is to many buildings you are turning from a vector to an image.